# VSCode extension API for adding line markings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[WallabyJS](https://wallabyjs.com/) adds this nice line markings to the editor. I've searched the [VSCode Extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) and couldn't find an API to add such color rectangles to lines. Any idea how?

[image: wallaby]

Answer (score 0):

That's done via the so-called [decorations API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor.setDecorations), specifically a decoration with a gutter icon:

> ```ts
> gutterIconPath?: string | Uri
> ```
>
> An absolute path or an URI to an image to be rendered in the gutter.

[`DecorationRenderOptions.gutterIconPath`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions.gutterIconPath)